# sql syntax error (using jstl tags)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am taking `username`, `column name` and `new entry` to be updated from user in a jsp.
I am trying to update my SQL database table using jstl tags and also show the updated table.
The jsp page is not opening it is giving a message of syntax error in my update sql query.

my jsp page:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Found page</title>
    <style>
        a:link, a:visited {
            background-color:darkolivegreen;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            width:100px; 
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius:20px; 
        }


        a:hover, a:active {
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        header {
            background-color:teal;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
         #file {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;

        }

        #file td, #file th {
            border: 2px solid black;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;                
        }            

        #file tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;} 

        #file th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            background-color: lightslategray;
            color: white;
        }
        section {
            height:270px; 
            width:1050px;
            float:right;
            padding:87px;
        }
        footer {
            background-color:black;
            float:bottom;
            color:white;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
    <%
        String userName = null;
        String sessionID = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("user")) {
                    userName = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    %>
    <header>
        <h1>File Tracking System</h1>
        <div><span style="float:right">Hi <%=userName%></span></div> 
        <br>
        <form  style="float:right" action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
        </form>
        <br>
    </header>
    <br>
    <a href="file.jsp">1.Insert New File</a>        
    <a href="fileStatus.jsp">2.Change File Status</a>
    <a href="found.jsp">3.Search your File</a>
    <a href="checkstatus.jsp">4.Check File Status</a> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <form method="POST">
        User ID:<br><input type="text" name="user" value="" size="20" />
```

These options in dropdown list the spelling is same as my column name in userdetails table

```
        Alter:<br><select name="use">
            <option>userName</option>
            <option>password</option>
            <option>role</option>
            <option>firstname</option>
            <option>lastname</option>
            <option>departmentname</option>
            <option>email</option>
            <option>mobile</option>
        </select>
        New Entry:<br><input type="text" name="enter" value="" size="20" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <section>
        <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/login"
                           user="root"  password="root"/>
```

udate sql query-

It is in the form ( update table_name set table_column="xyz" where column_name= "abc"; )

```
        <sql:update dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
            update usertable set "${param.use}"="${param.enter}" where username="${param.user}";
        </sql:update>
        <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
            select * from usertable where username="${param.user}";
        </sql:query>

        <table id="file">
            <tr>  
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Department Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.username}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.password}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.role}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.firstname}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.lasttname}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.departmentname}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.email}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${row.mobile}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Copyright 2016 NSIC. All right reserved.                             
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

what should be the correct syntax for sql? Is there some other way i could do this?
I used an alternate way where i submit values in `alter.jsp` and get them in a servlet `changeServlet.java` but it does not show any error and is not getting redirected anywhere it is simply opening http://localhost:8080/test9/changeServlet and is stuck here showing a white blank page.

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class changeServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies != null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
        if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
            System.out.println("JSESSIONID="+cookie.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
    }       
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println("admin="+session.getAttribute("admin"));
   if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("admin") != null){
               String admin=(String)session.getAttribute("admin"); 
                boolean status=false;
    try{
        String user=request.getParameter("user");
        String column=request.getParameter("column");
        String data=request.getParameter("data");            
        boolean checkc=checkchar.value(column);
        boolean checkp=checkchar.value(data);
```

the if statement is checking for any wrong entry or null value when submit wrong entry it redirects to `entry.jsp`. This means it is working till here but after this not working.

```
        if(checkc==true&&checkp==true) {
        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="update usertable set '"+column+"'='"+data+"' where username='"+user+"'";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);

        int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(rs>0){status=true;}

            if(status){
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.print("data updated,"+admin);
                  response.sendRedirect("updated.jsp");
                        }
              else 
              {   
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.print("failed to update");
                  response.sendRedirect("notinsert.jsp");
              }
            }
        else{response.sendRedirect("entry.jsp");}
            }catch(SQLException e){}  
              }else{
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
    rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: add single quotes arround the char values

Comment: do you mean like this------update usertable set '${param.use}' = '{param.enter}' where username= '${param.user}' ;

Comment: No i mean `update usertable set ${param.use}='${param.enter}' where username='${param.user}';`

Comment: i tried this also its not working

Comment: Can you describe "not working"? Any error message?

Comment: status 500 error It shows   update usertable set =' ' where username=' ';
and says sql syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will not work until these things  are modified:

1. your option tag

```html
<option value="userName">userName</option>
<option value="password">password</option>
<option value="role">role</option>
<option value="firstname">firstname</option>
<option value="lastname">lastname</option>
<option value="department">departmentname</option>
<option value="email">email</option>
<option value="mobile">mobile</option>
```

2. You are directly firing query on same page, i.e, you have shown the box, and immediately after it your query is there for update.

this causes problem because JSTL always runs first at server side so it doesn't matter where you write it, it will be executed first, now while executing that query, jstl founds that the parameters are null, so now query becomes something like this.:-

```
UPDATE TABLE `table-name` SET `null`=null where `user-name`=null;`
```

you can see in `null=null` column-name is itself being null, one can consider for `null` values but your column name too is `null`, and that doesn't exist in database or table.

so please make it in two jsp pages one will collect info and pass them as parameter to another jsp page, now this page must contain query, now it can fetch parameters value in query properly.

Comment: In above code I have given the alternative method of passing values from jsp and using then in servlet there is some error in it could you check that.

Comment: Yes, there is error in your code.   the form you are submitting is not setting any parameter to detect where to go in servlets and also if I have not mistaken then you might be getting either parameter values as null or null pointer exception (when using this null parameter in query.). Error(not actually error but a mistake) is on <form> tag, set action to indicate where to go and what to do.